# Android lunching intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I want to open my application through notification and this is the padding intent

```
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    viewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    viewIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_1, "someExtra");
    viewIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_2, "someExtra");
    viewIntent.setAction("action name");

    PendingIntent viewPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    return viewPendingIntent;
```

and if from now this intent is the lunching intent and if i try to open the the application from the recent application he will fire the same notification intent

i don't wan't that the notification intent   will be the lunching intent

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to open MainActivity on tap of the notification.

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```